# Thumbdrive doesn't show up on file manager. Can't mount it with terminal either

Tags: usb-drive

Xubuntu 22.04.2 LTS detects it but I can't access its contents

[image]

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** To help in troubleshooting your issue, please edit your question to include the version of the Ubuntu OS that you're running. That said, and looking at the image you provided, I see an error _"wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb, missing codepage or helper program, or other error."_ I would suspect that this is your issue. You may want to confirm the error and reformat this device.

Comment: I already formatted to NTFS with Disks

Comment: You should normally create one or more partitions on the drive, and create a file system in each partition, and mount them. Please try [again] to create a partition and file system. The partitions will be seen as devices `/dev/sdx1`, `/dev/sdx2` ... where x is a letter, for example `b`.

Comment: yeah, that was it. i partitioned it with gparted. so many steps that it's just a couple of clicks on Windows, gd.